# Как реализовать рисование кистью

Tags: c#, алгоритм, winforms, gdi

В начале просто рисовал на onMouseMove закрашенный эллипс с текущей координатой, но столкнулся с проблемой что не получается непрерывной линии.

Решил соединить точки линиями, но вылезла другая проблема - на большой толщине при поворотах углы начала и конца линий как бы вылазили за зону мазка и выглядывали ежиком.

Решил вернутся к первому варианту, но вместо одной точки рисовать много точек со смещением. Но и тут проблема, из-за наложение портится сглаживание, мазок становится грубым, да еще и прозрачность нивелируется. Плюс либо добавляешь много промежуточных точек и все начинает тормозить, либо на большой скорости все равно разрывы.

[image: Пример]

Вопрос как это реализуется в различных графический редакторах? Разгребать кучу абстракций из какого-нибудь open source приложения влом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий код:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            DoubleBuffered = true;
            Size = new Size(500, 500);
            MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
            Paint += Form1_Paint;
        }

        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (points.Count > 1)
            {
                using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 20))
                {
                    pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
                    pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
                    pen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
                    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                    e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                points.Add(e.Location);
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы не было мерцания при прорисовке, устанавливаем свойство `DoubleBufferd = true` у того контрола, на котором рисуем (в данном случае у формы).

Чтобы концы линий были круглыми, задаём перу свойства `StartCap` и `EndCap`. Чтобы не было неровных соединений линий, задаём перу свойство `LineJoin`.

Ну и, наконец, чтобы линии не были "ёжиком", задаём графиксу `SmoothingMode`.

Comment: pen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round; то чего мне не хватало